# Ng-class doesn't work with brackets in <fieldName>

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal with two input fields and I'm trying to give an `ng-class` to the `form-group` if `$invalid` on submit.

For that, I'm doing:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': item.answer[field2].$invalid }">
    <label>{% verbatim %}{{ model.structure.field2 }}{% endverbatim %}</label>
    <textarea name="answer[field2]" class="form-control"
              ng-model="model.answer.field2" ng-required="true">
     </textarea>
</div>
```

Keeping in mind that I need to keep the name `answer[field2]` unless it's the only way, is there a workaround for the brackets?

Also tried `answer[field2].$invalid`, `item.answer[field2].$invalid` and `item.answer.field2.$invalid`, but din't work.

Comment: Let's say that the wrapping form is something like `<form name="myForm">` then it should work using `ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.answer[field2].$invalid }"`

Comment: @AlonEitan it should and I'm doing the same with other twig templates (no brackets there) and they work fine

Comment: And just to be sure - The class is NOT added? Is it possible that the class itself is being added but there's no specific style for it?

Comment: Good point, but no, the class is not added

Comment: Sorry, i'm out of ideas then. Hope you'll get your answer soon enough

Comment: Thank you for trying :)

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem *in the question itself.*

Comment: Is `$scope.item.answer` an object or an array? Is `$scope.field2` a number or a string?  Why did you name the form `item`? That's a bit strange.

Comment: @georgeawg It's an object and a string, but I already figured it out (and answered it myself). About the name, was just an easier word to use as example for the question. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that when comes to a name containing brackets, brackets notation is the way to go:

`item['answer[field2]'].$invalid`